# problem with iterating over an imported module function in python

Tags: python, module

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
import StaticGillespie_SEIR_func as seirFunc 
# a module in which the function "main" returns a stochastic dynamical path
.
.
.
for i in varList:
    t_arr, _, _, I_arr, R_arr = seirFunc.main(G, expRate, infRate, recRate, t_max)
```

so far so good. code works perfectly.

However, when I try to iterate over it to generate say 10 realizations of my dynamical function, it works only for the first iteration and the imported function seems to stop working!

```
import StaticGillespie_SEIR_func as seirFunc  
.
.
.
for i in varList:
    for realization in range(10):
        t_arr, _, _, I_arr, R_arr = seirFunc.main(G, expRate, infRate, recRate, t_max)
```

I'm really confused. I checked every input to the function and it all looks allright to me. every thing is logically OK.

Any ideas why this happens?! Is there a condition in iterating over a module function that I don't know of?!

Comment: How is `seirFunc.main` defined?

Comment: can you provide code for the seirFunc.main function please?

Comment: Are you making the assumption that on import, the imported module execute the main function?  It doesn't

Comment: @XxJames07- That's an almost 150 line function ... what kind of information should I provide that you may need? there is only one function "main" that is like: 
def main(G, expRate, infRate, recRate, t_max): ... return t_arr, S_arr, E_arr, I_arr, R_arr

Comment: @Axe319 it is defined as:  def main(G, expRate, infRate, recRate, t_max): ... return t_arr, S_arr, E_arr, I_arr, R_arr, if that's what you mean

Comment: i meant that you should provide the definition of the function on the question itself.